# How to download diff data from opencellid using APIs?

Tags: database, api, cellid

I'm working with the data of opencellid, I do have in my database all the data from Brazil, but now it is necessary to keep this updated. To do this, I want to use an API in Python which every day goes to opencellid and get the diff data (OCID-diff-cell-export-2021-03-26-T000000.csv), but I only was able to find APIs which give me information from a specified cell. So, how can I keep my database updated using only APIs?